# Проблема в отображении записей блога на странице: "не удаётся выполнить запрос"

Tags: phpmyadmin, openserver, php7.2, laravel-5.7

Пытаюсь запустить страницу с отображением записей блога. Механизм следующий:
1) в  Eloquent-модели "Blog" использую  метод:

```
class Blog extends Model
{ 
   public function getTable(){
    $blog_post = Blog::all();
    return $blog_post;                    
}
}
```

2) в контроллере "IndexController" использую метод:

```
   public function indexBlog(){
    $title = 'Блог'.PageInfoController::getTitle();
    $blog = new Blog();
    return view('blog')->with(['title' => $title,
        'author' => PageInfoController::getAuthor(),
        'group' => PageInfoController::getGroup(),
        'blogs' => $blog->getTable(), 
        'count' => count($blog->getTable()),
        'copyright' => PageInfoController::getCopyright()]);
  }
```

3) на самой странице (blog.blade.php) :

```
<!doctype html>
<?php
        if(isset($_GET['form_author'])){
           $blogController = new \App\Http\Controllers\BlogController();
            $blogController->
            add($_GET['form_topic'],$_GET['form_author'],
                          $_GET['form_photo'],$_GET['form_message']);
            header('Location: /blog');
            exit();
        }
 ?>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
       ....
        <title>{{ $title }}</title>
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
     family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


 </head>
    <body>
   ...

    <div class="header">

            <?php
            $menu = new \App\Http\Controllers\PageInfoController();
            echo $menu->getMenu('Блог');
            ?>

    </div>

      ...
            <div class='info'>
                <h1>{{ $author }}</h1>
                <h2 class='text-muted'>{{ $group }}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="lead">Блог</p>

           <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal"
    method="post" id="form">

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label for=form_topic>Тема сообщения</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name=form_topic
     id=form_topic placeholder="Тема сообщения">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label for=form_author>Автор</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name=form_author
      id=form_author placeholder="Автор">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label for=form_photo>Фотография</label>
                    <input type="file" accept=".png,.jpeg,.jpg" 
                                                    name=form_photo 
                                                        id=form_photo>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label for=form_message>Сообщение</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name=form_message 
                                              id=form_message rows="3"
                                                placeholder="Сообщение">
                    </textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input id="submit" class="form-control btn btn-block 
                      btn-primary" 
               disabled type="submit" value="Отправить">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input class="form-control btn btn-block btn-default" 
      type="reset" value="Очистить">
                </div>
            </div>

          </form>



                   <div class="block-info">
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="4">Сообщения</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Cтатья</th>
                                <th>Автор</th>
                                <th>Фотография</th>
                                <th>Сообщение</th>
                                <th>Дата</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @if(!empty($blogs))
                                @foreach ($blogs as $blog)
                                 <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $blog->id }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $blog->Topic }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $blog->PathToPhoto }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $blog->Message }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $blog->Author }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $blog->CurrentDate }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            @endif  
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block-info">
                        Всего сообщений: {{ $count }}
                    </div>
                </div>
   <footer class='footer'>
      <div class='container'>

        <p class="text-muted pull-right">{{ $copyright }}</p>
    </div>
</footer>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.2.0.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js//time.js') }}"></script>
<!--script src="{{ asset('js/history.js') }}"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

В результате браузер пишет сообщение "не удаётся выполнить запрос", перезагрузка страницы возвращает тоже самое. Объясните пожалуйста, в чём причина ошибки и есть ли альтернативный подход к отображению данных на странице? 
Примечание: таблица записей блога создана, но пуста.

Comment: <?php
            $menu = new \App\Http\Controllers\PageInfoController();
            echo $menu->getMenu('Блог');
            ?> зачем вы это делаете вообще? зачем в blade шаблонах такое вытворять))

Comment: Учебный процесс иногда приносит "нестандартные" решения...

Answer (score 0):

Альтернативный подход заключается в следующем:
1.Модель Blog можно не использовать ( в данной ситуации её полностью очистить);
2.В контроллере "IndexController" прописать $blog = Blog::all(), и замент $blog->getTable() на $blog;
3. страницу "blog.blade.php" можно оставить без изменений.